# A word to cover meanings of religion, mysticism, occult, and philosophy

Tags: single-word-requests, metaphors

Is there a word (or maybe a metaphor) to cover the idea of religion, mysticism, occult, and philosophy all together?

In other words, how would you name a bookshelf with books and other texts by or about the following authors?

- Thomas Aquinas
- George Gurdjieff
- Aleister Crowley
- Aristotle

Comment: 'Spiritual' is a much-overworked word sometimes seen in bookshops. But I think philosophy, at least, doesn't really overlap sufficiently.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've edited the question to point that if there is no exact word, a metaphor is also sufficient for me.

Comment: *Metaphoricals*? *Isms*?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I don't think _metaphoricals_ is a good choice. The word is far away from the things it should describe.

Comment: On a shelf labelled *esoteric*, or *arcane*?

Comment: _Abstractions_. You can keep your math books there, too. _Mythos_ would work as well.

Comment: One might question why this shelf is trying to serve so many purposes. While some branches of philosophy are intertwined with religion, many are explicitly not. This shelf threatens to devolve into "Stuff people think about," and collapse. Admittedly, if you have a "philosophy" shelf and "spirituality" shelf, you might have a hard time categorizing certain people like Descartes, Swedenborg, or indeed Aristotle. But that might be a better challenge than hunting through the same shelf to find both Nietzche and Augustine.

Comment: What John said. **mythos** - *A body of interconnected myths or stories, esp. those belonging to a particular religious or cultural tradition. More generally: **an ideology, a set of beliefs** (personal or collective).*

Comment: Professional philosophers have traditionally worked very hard to separate their work from both the mythological accounts of the world and from various ideologies. They would perceive somebody's lumping all these things together as either a misunderstanding of what philosophy is, or (when it comes from somebody well-educated) as a deliberate put-down.

Comment: Theosophy? Although this word is closely associated with Helena Blavatsky and her Theosophical Society.

Comment: Dictionary.com defines [gnosis](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gnosis) as knowledge of spiritual matters; mystical knowledge.

Comment: Those are all *occult* except philosophy, which goes on its own shelf... in the basement, and just throw all those others away.

Comment: Philosophy can refer to a specific abstract system of thought ("Plato's philosophy"), or the academic discipline which analyses and questions such systems. With religion, there's a distinction between religion (the system of thought) and theology (the analysis). So which meaning of philosophy do you want? And are you excluding theology from your shelf?

Comment: "how would you name a bookshelf with books and other texts by or about the following authors?" Books about them could go under Biography

Comment: `Metaphysical` comes to mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have a hard time finding a single word that is broadly understood to encompass all of the authors and topics you list.

In bookshops, I often see a shelf labelled "Religion & Spirituality". Since that may or may not include classical philosophy, you might prefer

> Spirituality & Philosophy

But if you really need a single word, how about

> Thought

?

Comment: Isn't religion is a sub-conception of spirituality? I myself think the closest thing is to call it "Religion, mysticism, philosophy", but this is neither a single word nor a short and nice metaphor, not even close.

Comment: Yes, and that's the reason I suggest "spirituality and philosophy". I am curious as to why you need it to be a single word. In my experience, not all ideas can be given a one-word name (that is meaningful to more people than the writer, i.e. without coining a new usage).

Comment: Another user suggested "Esoteric" (esoterica?) in a comment to your question, which is not a bad fit for your examples, taken as a collection.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread your answer as "Spirituality & **Religion**".

Comment: It's not just that, as this answer puts it, it would be hard to find a single word that encompasses all these fields but that it is not clear **why** one would want to do that.

Comment: @Glaucon — The term *esoterica* often refers to pornography.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I've never seen it used that way, not even online. That usage might not be as widespread as you think.

Comment: @TinfoilHat isn't that *erotica*? People misusing the word *esoterica* is no reason to stop using it.

Comment: @WeatherVane — No, it’s for real. From the *OED*: ***esoterica**, n. Esoteric objects or products; esoteric details; = ESOTERIC* adj. *1; pornography.* See also [-Ologies & -isms — A Thematic Dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ologies_isms/bgztbnUMuvkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=esoterica)

Comment: In any case, it doesn’t really matter how, er, widespread it is. Let me know, though, if your bookstore suddenly has a lot of new customers.

Comment: My bookshop welcomes anyone weird enough to go to the Oxford English Dictionary for stimulation, as long as they can behave themselves in public.

Comment: Certainly in the UK, *esoteric(a)* is used in this context.  There used to be a 2nd hand bookshop in Bristol that was about 50% esoterica but I was more interested in its selection of old maps.  That's sadly gone,  but [The Speaking Tree](https://www.speakingtree.co.uk/) in Glastonbury (where it's certainly in character for the town) describes itself as a specialist in esoteric books.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest [Western Esoteric Traditions](https://academic.oup.com/book/9553/chapter/156571347).

The four authors mentioned in OP's question, viz. Thomas Aquinas, George Gurdjieff, Aleister Crowley, and Aristotle all appear in the index of a book published by OUP in 2008 - The Western Esoteric Traditions: A Historical Introduction by Nicholas Goodrick-Clarke.

Comment: Many philosophers did not think of what they were doing as particularly esoteric. And some explicitly separated the esoteric and exoteric parts of their teachings.

Comment: Calling it 'Western' would mean you need a different shelf for *Bhagavad Gita* and *I Ching*.

Comment: Indeed. And psychologists are not usually pleased at being classified as European.

Comment: Valid points. I didn’t think it fully through. I happened to find the four names OP mentioned in the book I cited and suggested part of the title as a possibility.

Comment: This reflects the vagueness in the question. Aristotle certainly influenced a lot of esoteric and religious traditions, and some books about him would be relevant, but a lot of his writing would not be classed as religion or esoterica.

Answer (score 2):

Theosophy; the study/philosophy of, theology, philosophy, esotericism, and ethics, as well as any basic foundation type (though sometimes dated) ideological school of thought.. .

Comment: >As presented by Blavatsky, Theosophy teaches that there is an ancient and secretive brotherhood of spiritual adepts known as the Masters, who—although found around the world—are centered in Tibet. These Masters are alleged by Blavatsky to have cultivated great wisdom and supernatural powers, and Theosophists believe that it was they who initiated the modern Theosophical movement through disseminating their teachings via Blavatsky.

Comment: >They believe that these Masters are attempting to revive knowledge of an ancient religion once found around the world and which will again come to eclipse the existing world religions. Theosophical groups nevertheless do not refer to their system as a "religion". --- Yeah, no. That's just still religion. Not a bad answer tho.

Comment: It’s too bad the term *theosophy* has been co-opted by the [Theosophical Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theosophical_Society).

Comment: Theosophy: The attainment of direct, unmediated knowledge of the nature of divinity and the origin and purpose of the universe.  Smashed it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that theosophy is nowadays largely associated with Blavatsky: see the Wikipedia article on [Theosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theosophy). Of course you're free to call the section in the bookshelf anything you like, even "brainy stuff" or "thinky books", but it would be preferable to use a commonly-used, generally-understood term.

Answer (score 1):

This may not actually be what you are looking for, but it does further the "thought" theme from Glaucon above:

**Epistemology** - (n) a branch of philosophy that investigates the origin, nature, methods, and limits of human knowledge.

Comment: Epistemology, as the quoted definition says, is a **branch** of philosophy, while the OP seems to be looking for a word that encompasses all of it plus some other things. Some of the writings by Aristotle and Aquinas are on topics in epistemology, but most aren't.

Comment: To extend @jsw29's observation, I would be hard-pressed to describe Gurdijeff's work as epistemology, and Crowley's work is definitely not about theories of knowledge. However, as a sibling answer notes, all four wrote about metaphysics. To be pithy: epistemology is "how do we know about that?" while metaphysics is "does that exist?"

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***weltanschauung*** or ***worldview**.*

From Wiktionary on *[weltanschauung](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weltanschauung):*

> A person's or a group's conception, philosophy or view of the world; a worldview.

… and [worldview](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worldview):

> 1. One's personal view of the world and how one interprets it.
> 2. The totality of one's beliefs about reality.
> 3. A general philosophy or view of life.

Also Wikipedia on [worldview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldview):

> A **worldview** or a **world-view** or **Weltanschauung** is the fundamental cognitive orientation of an individual or society encompassing the whole of the individual's or society's knowledge, culture, and point of view. A worldview can include natural philosophy; fundamental, existential, and normative postulates; or themes, values, emotions, and ethics.

In my understanding this fails to capture the more practical aspects of philosophy, religion, and occultism such as applied ethics, rituals, or religious communities. However, my educated guess is that this is not what you are after.